# Extract comment written in Chinese and translate them into English using some script

Tags: c++, google-translator-toolkit

I have a C++ project in which comments of source code are in Chinese language, now I want to convert them into English.
I tried to solve using google translator but got an Issue: Whole CPP files or header didn't get converted, also I have found the name of the struct, class etc gets changed. Sometimes code also gets modified.

Note: Each .cpp or .h file is less than 1000 lines of code.But there are multiple C++ projects each having around 10 files. Thus I have around 50 files for which I need to translate Chinese text to English.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064114/translating-comments-and-region-names-in-source-code

Comment: You could copy&paste each comment one by one. Or you could write some script which keeps only comments.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: The link I provided uses PrepTools which translates a wide variety of text using regex

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch One by one would be last choice, is there anything else you can suggest

Comment: BTW, names (of functions, of classes, of methods, of variables, ...) are probably also in Chinese, and that could be more an issue

Comment: How large is that C++ project? (millions of source code lines, or just thousands)... What do you need to do with it?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Source codes are just thousands of lines or less. Also only comments are in chinese. But in google translator it capitalize start word of line and also do some small changes in english language that hurts

Comment: Both answers fit. But please, *don't comment* your question but improve (it needs a lot of improvement and context)

Comment: For such as small program, I would just edit it by hand and copy&paste manually some comments into GoogleTranslate. *Understanding* the program would take much more time than changing comments!

Answer (score 3):

Well, what did you expect? Google Translate doesn't know what a CPP file is and how to treat it. You'll have to write your own program that extracts comments from them (not that hard), runs just those through Google Translate, and then puts them back in.

Mind you, if there is commented out code, or the comments reference variable names, those will get translated too. Detecting and handling these cases is a lot harder already.

Answer (score 2):

Extracting comments is a [lexical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexing) issue, and mostly a quite simple one.

In a few hours, you could write (e.g. with [flex](https://github.com/westes/flex)) some simple command line program extracting them. And a good editor (such as [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)) could even be configured to run that filter on selected code chunks.

(handling a few corner cases, such as [raw string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), might be slightly more difficult, but these don't happen often and you might handle them manually)

BTW, if you are assigned to work on that code, you'll need to understand it, and that takes much more time than copy&pasting or editing each comments manually.

At last, I am not sure of the quality of automatic translation of code comments. You might be disappointed. Also, the code names (of functions, of classes, of variables, etc...) matter a lot more.

Perhaps *adding* your comments in English could be wiser.

Don't forget to use some version control system. You really need one (e.g. [`git`](http://git-scm.com/))

<sup>(I am not convinced that extracting comments for automatic translation would help your work)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

First separate both comment and code part in different file using python script as below,

```
import sys 
file=sys.argv[1]
f=open(file,"r")
lines=f.readlines()
f.close()
comment=open("comment.txt","w+")
code=open("code.txt","w+")
for l in lines:
  if "//" in l:                                                                                                                                      
    comment.write(l)
    code.write("\n")
  else:
    code.write(l)
    comment.write("\n")
comment.close()
code.close()
```

Now translate comment.txt with google translator and then use

```
paste code.txt comment_en > source
```

where comment_en is translated comment in english.